# How do I copy a file from one container to another container in the same pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a container (container1) which is basically just containing a file x in the /home directory.
I need to copy this file to another container (container2) in the same pod.

The yaml file is like this -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: app
  strategy:
     type: Recreate
  template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: app
     spec:
       initContainers:
         - name: container1
           image: container1:latest
           imagePullPolicy: Always
           command: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'cp /home/x /path/x']
           volumeMounts:
             - name: copy
               mountPath: /home
       containers:
         - name: container2
           image: container2:latest
           imagePullPolicy: Always
           volumeMounts:
             - name: copy
               mountPath: /path
       volumes:
         - name: copy
           emptyDir: {}
```

When I am running the deployment, I am getting the following log message and an Init:CrashLoopBackOff -

cp: cannot stat '/home/x': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to do what you say in case you have 2 Containers in the same Pod; what you can do is create a Volume and mount it to both Containers.
After that you will have both Containers having access to the same file and you can work with it however you like.

Take a look here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/